# Is hemomancy scientifically possible?

Tags: science-based, magic, super-powers

Like in anime where characters are able to control their blood to use as weapons and projectiles like chops from jujutsu Kaisen or power from chainsaw man.

Is it possible for a machine or biological creature to have the power of controlling their blood? Or does it go violate biological laws?

Also what are the limits of this ability through your science based solution? Can it be used to control all the blood of all living life or is it not possible at all?

Comment: We’re not a brainstorming site.questions asking us to build your world for you are not permitted.

Comment: Ok I’ll edit the question.

Comment: Also I just clarified the question to help make this question more eligible.

Comment: I have the power to control my blood, my heart pumps it all over the place. what do you mean by control?

Comment: Use the blood as a weapon in combat

Comment: Like shooting out the blood extremely fast like a water cutter but blood

Comment: You're now asking multiple questions in one post something also not permitted on this site.

Comment: A few notes. A "-mancy" is a form of divination. For instance, necromancy is communicating with the dead (and sometimes convincing them to re-animate their bodies). What you're looking for is hemokinetics or hemolurgy. Second, are you counting the spontaneous loss of blood pressure that would result from having much of your blood suddenly outside your body? Third, the examples you provide involve psychokinetic manipulation. That's psychokinesis, regardless of what you're kinesing, so you're going to get a "no, it's magic" answer.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what blood you are talking about and what you mean by "control".  You already do "control" the flow of your blood via the contraction of smooth muscles in the blood vessels.  You just don't do so consciously.  Some organisms have more conscious control over those muscles than you do.  Horned Toads can shoot a jet of blood from their eyes.  Whales and other cetaceans can shunt blood away from their fins, concentrating it in the more vital central regions when diving or swimming in cold water.  It is theoretically possible that a person in a story setting could have an incredible amount of fine control over their own circulatory system.  Of course, you aren't actually controlling the blood itself, but the muscles that are responsible for moving it around.  If you are talking about telekinetic control of blood not in your body via spooky action at a distance, then no, but "mancy" implies magic, which means just science what you want to science and handwave the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [horned lizards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horned_lizard) are able to shoot blood from their eyes, so there is no biological rule against using blood as a weapon or projectile.

Blood is a fluid, and so it should generally be limited to the sort of things that animals achieve by launching fluids. So, for example, [archer fish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archerfish) are famous for their ability to shoot down insects around 3 meters away or so.

Many of the other animals which [use ranged attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectile_use_by_non-human_organisms) rely on the unpleasant nature of the fluid itself, shooting venom, acid, etc.

The absence of an animal that uses thrown liquids without any other negative properties (acid, venom, stinky) to attack peers seems to indicate that they aren't a great mechanism for that sort of thing.